# What php Headers do I need to play an audio file

Tags: php, audio, http-headers

I have decrypted my audio file, I now want to play it and then unlink it.
What I currently have is:

```
<?php
    $destination = "/tmp_upload_dir_copy/test.mp3"
    header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');
    readfile($destination); 
    unlink($destination);
?>
```

Anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong or what else do I need?

maybe I need to use fpassthru() ?

Comment: What's the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: do you want to play it on the client or the server?

Comment: You'd need a player app on the client-side, or at least a browser that's got a plugin that auto-plays mp3s.

Comment: did you try audio/mp3 ??? and give a filesize with header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));

Comment: I need to be able to delete the file after it has been played

Comment: I think Marc B might be right in that I'm taking the wrong approach using headers. But I still don't know how to go about playing a file and then deleting it when it's finished playing?

Comment: you want to delete it from the client?

Comment: I want to decrypt an audio file placing it in a temp directory, have it played and then delete the decrypted file. the decrypted file will be on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you don't really want to delete the file immediately, as any number of things could go wrong on the user's end between downloading the mp3 and actually playing it.  The user might need to initiate the file transfer again in many cases. Instead you might want to set up a cron job that runs every night and deletes the mp3 files that are more than one day old.  (Also, I'm not sure what you meant by "decrypt" the audio file.)

Comment: Thanks Matt.
I was thinking that this might be too much of a hack like solution but the more I think about it, the more I think it's the only way.

Comment: Also to answer your question; what I was trying to achieve was the ability to hold audio files on the server in a secure fashion. This meant that I needed to encrypt the files and then when it came to play the files I would need to decrypt them. This lead to the problem of deleting the files once they have been played and that is where I think your answer gives me my only solution. The only other solution would be to give the ability to encrypt / decrypt to the user and have a condition that you can’t play in less the file is decrypted. However this solution would be against the specifications

Answer (score 1):

PHP works only server side. You can only guarentee the file is SENT to the client, but there is no way to directly make sure it has been PLAYED by the client.

Setting the header will only influence how the browser treats the data (in this case the browser is informed the data is audio). Chrome, for example plays audio files but some browsers may give users a download prompt.

You'll need client side software, like a audio playing component (search "Flash MP3 player") to embed in a page to play the audio file.